# Measure theoretic proof of Leibniz Rule for Differentiation under the Integral with varying integration limits

Tags: integration, measure-theory, derivatives

I'm searching for a rigorous proof of Leibniz rule of integration for varying integration limits, i.e.:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int^{b(x)}_{a(x)} f(x,t) dt = f(x,b(x)) \frac{db(x)}{dx} -
f(x,a(x)) \frac{da(x)}{dx} + \int^{b(x)}_{a(x)} \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x} dt.
$$
I've seen proofs of the statement above, but not in measure theoretic terms. Also, the proofs of Leibniz rule that use Measure Theory just prove for the case where the limits are fixed, i.e. (under proper hypothesis):
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_\Omega f(x,t) dt = \int_\Omega \frac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x,t) dt.
$$
I've tried extending the proof by using the result above and using an indicator function to write the limits as a function inside of the integral. But, I then end up having to integrate an indicator function.

If someone can prove the result or point me to a reference that does the complete proof, I'd really appretiate it.

Comment: For constant $c \in (a(x), b(x))$, $$  \int_{a(b)}^{b(x)} = \int_{a(x)}^c + \int_c^{b(x)}  \text{.}$$  You should have no trouble finding a proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus for the Lebesgue integral, appearing as item 2 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions), to resolve these integrals.